# Give specific controller to a specific pawn dynamically?

Tags: controller, spawn, unreal-engine4, blueprint, asymmetric

I have to create an asymmetric game in blueprint. I got 2 different pawns spawning in each level. Each pawn has to have a specific controller because we need different views, controls and characters. 
So, spawnActor is the answer to spawn a pawn I assume, but as it is a multiplayer game, we're going threw onPostLogin function belonging to our gameMode. OnPostLogin is giving us a playerController ( the default one I think ).
How can I change this one dynamically ? Why can't I cast It into my specific player controller ?

Apologize about my english, kind regards. 
Yaël.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason you shouldn't be able to cast the incoming PlayerController to your custom controller. Can you give more information, perhaps screenshots?

Comment: Sorry about the delay, I posted this question somewhere else and then forgot I did here as well. My bad JonS. We finally merge both controller into one.